# How to add many point of intersection to a TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \a/\text in {0/,60/,120/,180/,240/,300/} 
    \draw[] (\a:1cm) circle (1.5cm) node[right] () {\text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

generates 6 circles intersecting at 30 points. Is there a possibility to put, e.g., dots in all the points of intersection without manual calculations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean by "without manual calculation" that analytic computations are to be avoided, then you can use the `intersections` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\newcounter{myintersection}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[int/.code={\stepcounter{myintersection}%
    \tikzset{name=i-\number\value{myintersection},circle,draw,inner sep=1pt}}]
 \foreach \a/\mytext [count=\X]in {0/,60/,120/,180/,240/,300/} 
    {\draw[name path=\X-path] (\a:1cm) circle[radius=1.5cm] node[right] {\mytext};
    \ifnum\X>1
     \foreach \Y in {1,...,\the\numexpr\X-1}
     {
     \path[name intersections={of=\X-path and
     \Y-path,total=\t}]
     foreach \Z in {1,...,\t}
      {(intersection-\Z) node[int]{}};}
    \fi
    }
\typeout{\number\value{myintersection} intersections found} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Ti*k*Z also finds 30 intersections, and gave them the names `i-1` to `i-30`.

**ADDENDUM**: This is a version that checks if the intersection number is greater than zero. In the above case, this is not necessary, but in other applications it might be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\newcounter{myintersection}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[int/.code={\stepcounter{myintersection}%
    \tikzset{name=i-\number\value{myintersection},circle,draw,inner sep=1pt}}]
 \foreach \a/\mytext [count=\X]in {0/,60/,120/,180/,240/,300/} 
    {\draw[name path=\X-path] (\a:1cm) circle[radius=1.5cm] node[right] {\mytext};
    \ifnum\X>1
     \foreach \Y in {1,...,\the\numexpr\X-1}
     {
     \path[name intersections={of=\X-path and
     \Y-path,total=\t}] \ifnum\t>0
     foreach \Z in {1,...,\t}
      {(intersection-\Z) node[int]{}}\fi;}
    \fi
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! I was afraid that the basic understanding of TikZ is not enough.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke It is a nested loop. The outer loop is the one from your question, the next level is `\foreach \Y in {1,...,\the\numexpr\X-1}`, which is over all earlier circles, and then `foreach \Z in {1,...,\t}` loops over all intersections wit the previous circle. (In this case we know that `\t=2`, and if you ever extend this to a situation whether there cases without intersections, you'd need `\ifnum\t>0
  foreach \Z in {1,...,\t}
   {(intersection-\Z) node[int]{}}\fi`.